# Break data into array elements based of two or more spaces

Tags: php, regex, file, pattern-matching

I'm trying to parse a tabbed text file which has on a single line multiple parts of data, the only way to differentiate between each part of data is that the parts are separated by gaps of two or more spaces or tabs.

I've found tons of answers on stack about replacing multiple spaces to a single space but haven't been able to get anything to answer my issue, I've tried playing around with the regex patterns to no avail.

```
 DER V3,0,0,3323  Xkisjd                 2014 02 25 05:23    PGM / RUN BY / DATE
```

I was using something like this but it doesn't affect the data I would suspect this is due to the data begin separated by a tab.

```
 preg_split("/\s\s+/", $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

I would appreciate any help I can get or suggestions.

Expected outcome would be an array:

```
 PGM => DER V3,0,0,3323
 RUN BY => Xkisjd
 DATE => 2014 02 25 05:23
```

Comment: What is your expected output? put in your code.

Comment: Did you even bother to take a look at the documentation of the `preg_split()` function? It does not alter the `$data` argument you hand over, it _returns_ an array.

Comment: @arkascha, I'd be happy with an array which is why I was trying to use it, once I get the dash in I was going to explode it but found that it could all be done in one call by using the preg_split if I could get the correct pattern. I'll reword my question, sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your `preg_split` a bit. Check this out:-

```
<?php
 $string ='DER V3,0,0,3323  Xkisjd                 2014 02 25 05:23    PGM / RUN BY / DATE'; 

echo "<pre/>";print_r(preg_split("/\s\s+/",$string));

 ?>
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/796wd7

If you want space will replace with `-` then do like this:-

```
$data = preg_replace("/\s\s+/", "-", $string);
echo $data;
```

Output:- http://prntscr.com/7972nf

Note:- It gives you an array. And i hope you know how to manipulate it according to your wish. thanks.

I edited my answer and add second one because your question is bit confusing.I hope it will help you thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are expecting the string to be updated after executing `preg_split`?

Refer to the manual: [preg_split](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) will split by the delimiter, so it will return an array. You need [preg_replace](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$data = preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", $data);
```

That will give you the desired result.

Another note: the subject of question says you want to replace *space*  ( ) characters with a *dash* (-) but in your question you talk about replacing *multiple spaces* with a *single space*?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest another approach with `preg_match_all`.

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/bA1zR9/1):

```
#^([a-z]+\s+[a-z]\d+(?:,\d+)+)\s*(\S+)\s*([\d:\s]+\d)\s*([^\/]+)\s+\/\s+([^\/]+)\s+\/\s+([^\/]+)\s+$#im
```

Here is a [sample code](https://ideone.com/YOxMzU):

```
$re = "/^([a-z]+\\s+[a-z]\\d+(?:,\\d+)+)\\s*(\\S+)\\s*([\\d:\\s]+\\d)\\s*([^\\/]+)\\s+\\/\\s+([^\\/]+)\\s+\\/\\s+([^\\/]+)\\s+$/mi"; 
$str = "DER V3,0,0,3323  Xkisjd                 2014 02 25 05:23    PGM / RUN BY / DATE \nVER V1,2,4,0003  MfgHJd                 2015 12 11 11:13    PGM / RUN BY / DATE "; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
$cnt = count($matches[0]);
$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
    $arrAdd = array();
    $arrAdd[$matches[4][$i].trim()] = $matches[1][$i];
    $arrAdd[$matches[5][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
    $arrAdd[$matches[6][$i]] = $matches[3][$i];
    array_push($arr, $arrAdd);
}
print_r($arr);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PGM] => DER V3,0,0,3323
            [RUN BY] => Xkisjd
            [DATE] => 2014 02 25 05:23
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PGM] => VER V1,2,4,0003
            [RUN BY] => MfgHJd
            [DATE] => 2015 12 11 11:13
        )

)
```